# How Super user can access tokens of other users

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt

I need to delete normal user account from superuser account. As user accounts are authenticated using token authentication, I think it will be needed to access user's token and pass it with the request header to make `POST`,`PUT`,`DELETE` actions on it.
So is there any way to access it? Or is there any other substitute way to implement this?

Comment: Can you redefine your question more clearly... You have a user account you need removed with an attached token, but you may still need access to that token once deleted?

Comment: No, that's exactly not my case. I have two types of user accounts. Normal user accounts and superuser account. I need to delete a user account from superuser account using `DELETE` request

Comment: But since all the user profiles are authenticated, we may have to provide authentication credentials to perform `POST` or `DELETE` requests

Comment: Or along with the `POST` or `DELETE` request, we should have to attach the authorisation header., ie the token value in this case

Comment: Am I clear to you?